# Fatal nil Error when trying to present menu scene and create a button(swift SpriteKit)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, fatal-error

I am trying to present a menu scene as the first scene in my game, and my menu has a play button on it, but when I run it I get a fatal nil unwrapping error.

Here is some code in my gameViewController:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    if let scene = StartMenu(fileNamed: "StartMenu") {
            // Configure the view.
            let skView = self.view as! SKView
            skView.showsFPS = true
            skView.showsNodeCount = true
            skView.showsPhysics = true
            skView.showsDrawCount = true

            /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */

            if(skView.scene == nil){

                scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
                scene.size  = skView.bounds.size
                scene.backgroundColor = UIColor(hue: 0.5278, saturation: 0.75, brightness: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)
                skView.presentScene(scene)
            }


    }
}
```

and here is some code in my StartMenu file:(I marked where I got the fatal error)

```
class StartMenu: SKScene {
var font:String = "AmericanTypewriter-Bold"
var playButton: SKSpriteNode!

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    let title = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: font)
    title.text = "Turtle Run"
    title.fontName = font
    title.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: self.frame.size.height-40)
    self.addChild(title)
    

    playButton = self.childNode(withName: "playButton") as? SKSpriteNode
    playButton.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "playButton") //I get the fatal error here!!!
    playButton.size = CGSize(width: self.frame.size.height/5, height: self.frame.size.height/5)
    playButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: self.frame.size.height/2)
    
}
```

I also have a StartMenu.sks file where I dragged in a color sprite and named it playButton. I made sure to name the sprite playButton and make it's class StartMenu, so I'm not sure why I am getting an error.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!!!

Comment: Clearly `self.childNode(withName: "playButton") as? SKSpriteNode` yields `nil`.

Comment: “name the sprite playButton and make it's class StartMenu” Really?

Comment: @matt thanks, but how can I fix it?

Comment: Well like I said, “name the sprite playButton and make it's class StartMenu”. If you really did that, there’s your answer.

Comment: @matt I’m sorry if this is a silly question, I’m not very experienced with coding. Are you saying that I shouldn’t have done that? Maybe I’m just not understanding. Thanks for ur help!

Comment: Well StartMenu is not an SKSpriteNode. So when your code asks if this thing is a SKSpriteNode, the answer is no and you get nil. But surely you never meant the play button to be a StartMenu....?

Comment: @matt you are so right, I can't believe I passed over that so many times and didn't catch it!

Comment: I asked you twice about it.